# How to flush the file write buffer in running python process with no file.close() statement?

Tags: python, file, buffer

I have a file that is being written to in a background Python 3.5 process. The file was opened in this process (which is basically a running Python script) but I forgot to include a file close statement to flush out the buffer occasionally in that script. The script is infinite unless it is ended manually and I (now) know that killing the python process will cause all the data in the buffer to be lost. Is there anyway to recover the data to be written in this already running process?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1) Get the PID of your python process

```
pgrep python
```

2) List file descriptors

```
ls -l /proc/{PID}/fd
```

3) Open gdb

```
$ gdb
(gdb) attach {PID}
(gdb) call fflush({FILE_DESCRIPTOR})
(gdb) detach
```

4) Check your file

Comment: Is the file descriptor a number or a name (with directory)?

Comment: the file descriptor is the number. the standards FD are: 0 for stdin, 1 for stdout, 2 for stderr.

Comment: I ended up getting this:

Program received signal SIGSEGV, Segmentation fault.
0x00007f487134d93d in fflush () from /lib64/libc.so.6
The program being debugged was signaled while in a function called from GDB.
GDB remains in the frame where the signal was received.
To change this behavior use "set unwindonsignal on".
Evaluation of the expression containing the function
(fflush) will be abandoned.

Comment: do not stop gdb, detach first. do not use quit gdb

Comment: I already did unfortunately, but for future reference, what was the issue ?

Comment: @Omnomnious the logs didn't save? I think a simple Ctrl+C would have worked

Comment: No, I lost the data in the end. What do you mean Ctrl+C? In GDB or in the process itself?

Comment: @Omnomnious In the process itself.

Comment: The process was a background one and using Ctrl+C would have caused the program to crash losing all the data.

Answer (score 5):

[As per the docs](https://docs.python.org/2/library/os.html#os.fsync)

> first do `f.flush()`, and then do `os.fsync(f.fileno())`, to ensure that all internal buffers associated with f are written to disk.

Here is an example,

```
import os

with open("filename", "w") as f:
    while True:  # infinite program
        f.write("the text")
        f.flush()
        os.fsync(f.fileno())
```

Comment: Sorry, I wasn't clear enough. The process is already running and I want to recover it from this running process.

Comment: Ah. That's harder then. You'll probably have to use gdb... I think I'll leave this here as a reminder though - you won't want to forget to do this after you quit your program :P